# How to create a unique alphanumeric id each time and ensure it doesn't exist in my existing list using python?

Tags: python

I need to assign a unique name that contains the word 'user' and a certain random numbers to a user. Something like `user32944`, `user80890` etc. So I write a program something like this

```
import random

user_list = ["user32944", "user60690"] # essentially this list is what I retrieve from some database
user_name = ""
while(True):
    if user_name not in user_list:
        user_name = "user" + str(random.random() * 100000).split(".")[0]
        break

print(user_name)
```

But if I deliberately set the `user_name` to something that already exists in the list, my program doesn't exit the loop and the program hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should exit in the first run.

Comment: Put an else block incase the username already exists. PS. what do you want to do if it already exists?

Comment: The logic is wrong, you generate a new user name if it's *not* in the list of existing users, then *always* break. It certainly doesn't loop forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only perform a action when the generated username is not in the list, but you don't do anything when the username is in the list. And therefore you don't exit the while loop and the program will hang.

The following code sample does what you want. Although i recommend you to explore the [uuid package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) in python.

```
import random
user_list = ["user32944", "user60690"] # essentially this list is what I retrieve from some database

def generateRandomUsername():
    randomNr = random.randint(1,3)
    if randomNr == 1:
        return "user32944"
    else:
        return "user" + str(random.random() * 100000).split(".")[0]

def getRandomUniqueUsername():
    while(True): 
        username = generateRandomUsername() 
        if username not in user_list:
            print('Created user \'%s\'' % username) 
            return username
        else:
            print("Username \'%s\'already exists, generating new one" % username)

def printUsernameList():
    for username in user_list:
        print('Username: %s' % username)

#Create 4 random usernames
for i in range(4):
    username = getRandomUniqueUsername()
    user_list.append(username)
    print('Printing user_list...')
    printUsernameList()
```

Answer (score 0):

That will never exit the loop because you are never satisfying the IF condition and there is no conditional expression on while too, you gave True in while condition -> which means it loops infinitely.

So if you do not satsifying the IF condition then write a logic what you would want to do incase IF does not get statisified and then break out of the loop.

And if you want guid with just random alphanumeric ids, then use uuid package in python.